# Как изменить внешний вид PreferenceFragment в коде программы?

Tags: android, java

А именно цвет текста и высоту ячейки. Понимаю, что  нужно изменять в onCreateView. В данном случае:

```
public class MenuFragment extends PreferenceFragment { 
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main);
 }
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if (v != null) {
       ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
       lv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
  return v;
 }
}
```

я подсмотрел, что можно найти android.R.id.list в View. А где можно узнать, какие ещё элементы содержатся в данном View?

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает сделать просто свой фрагмент со своими вьюхами и сохранять значения в настройках?

Честно, я не разбирался с PreferenceFragment, но думаю вам стоит ограничиться теми атрибутами, которые заданы в xml настроек или наследоваться от этого класса и веселиться дальше.

В догонку [Настройки в стиле Holo Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/151003/).